# Can you use the same view and angular controller without overwriting the data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, pdf-viewer

I have an application using a PDF viewer-pdf angularjs made, this viewer uses a html template
with its own controller angularjs, this viewer want to use it in different catalogs (ie it is
global) viewer, I work well when I open one PDF catalog and position, but when you open another
I unlocked the other loads the pdf in the previous window and no where open, ie data overwrites me
Is there any way to resolve this, open the same viewer in several catalogs without affecting others?

Answer (score 0):

If you make the PDF viewer a directive you should be able to achieve this because directives operate within their own scope.

Comment: I am using the directive that is in this url https://github.com/sayanee/angularjs-pdf, could be
as described above ?.

Comment: Oh ok. So it looks like on #6 of "Getting Started", you are setting a scope variable called pdfUrl. How are you changing this variable when you open a new instance of PDF viewer?

Comment: Could you try setting the pdfUrl variable in the controller instead of the service?

Comment: But I want to make dynamic, so that it can change from other drivers, I could not do it because I use the same controller and view for the viewer.

Answer (score 0):

That's why I created a service as shown:

```
angular.module('myModule',['pdf']).service('pdfService', function () {

    var pdfURL = "";

    var defineURL = function (url) {
        pdfURL = url;
    };

    var getURL = function () {
        return pdfURL;
    };

    return {
        defineURL: defineURL,
        getURL: getURL
    };

}).controller('DocControlador', ['$scope', 'pdfService', function ($scope, pdfService) {

    $scope.pdfName = '';
    $scope.pdfUrl = pdfService.getURL(); 
    $scope.scroll = 0;
    $scope.loading = 'cargando...';

    $scope.getNavStyle = function (scroll) {
        if (scroll > 100) return 'pdf-controls fixed';
        else return 'pdf-controls';
    }

    $scope.onError = function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    $scope.onLoad = function () {
        $scope.loading = '';
    }

    $scope.onProgress = function (progress) {
        console.log(progress);
    }

}])
```

and here I pass I assign values to the variables of service from another controller:

```
pdfService.defineURL("\\Files\\1\\Charts\\" + $scope.fileName);
```